# Spring-Boot Recources not found in static Folder if not jpeg or in sub folder

Tags: spring, image, spring-boot, rest

i have the following problem. I need several images for my application. If I add jpeg images under the following Path: src/main/resources/static/images/image.jpeg. I am able to use them under the following URL http://localhost:8080/images/image.jpeg.

However I am not able to find the same Image when I make a subfolder under Images.
In addition to that, if I have a JPG-File I am not even able to find the Image under the following Path src/main/resources/static/images/image.jpg.

I am new to Spring-Boot and in my understanding it should be possible to access these images without further effort.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Show your controller/config classes and jsp/html you have along with your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an image at this location - src/main/resources/static/img/abc.jpg

You should have your config like [this](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebMVC.java):

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
};

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

Then you should be able to view your image in your (say jsp) [like](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks) below:

```
 <img id="img" src="/img/abc.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It toes not work, but why is it also needed?  I thought Spring-Boot comes with a pre-configured implementation of ResourceHttpRequestHandler